# Data Type Mismatch in Criteria Expression Binary to Integer VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm writing an Excel Macro which works with an existing Access DB. Several of the queries I run will require input from the user as to which users they remove from a table, but seeing as the number will be the same each time I'd rather capture it once at the beginning of the macro and use that variable in my SQL statements. The number is for a quarter number of the year. So it'll either be 1,2,3 or 4 I can capture that from the user ok, but when I try to use the variable in an SQL statement I get the "Data Type Mismatch in Criteria error"

Here is what I'm trying:

```
Dim Qrtnum As Integer

Qrtnum = Application.InputBox("Enter Quarter to Sample")

sql1 = "DELETE SampledEmailAddressesByQuarter.*, SampledEmailAddressesByQuarter.Quarter FROM SampledEmailAddressesByQuarter WHERE SampledEmailAddressesByQuarter.Quarter = "

appAccess.DoCmd.RunSQL sql1 & Qrtnum
```

Now in the table in my database the data type is listed as "Binary" and I'm trying to pass an Int variable into my SQL, could this be the problem? Or is the fact I have an Int concatenated with my SQL String?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try using cstr to convert Qrtnum to a string  ie,:
`& cstr(Qrtnum)`

Comment: Does your `DELETE` work if you change the datatype of *SampledEmailAddressesByQuarter.Quarter* to Integer or Long Integer?

Comment: In response to Mark Moore, sadly that didn't do it for me. One thing I have tried is that it will work if I prompt for the quarter number as part of my SQL though with that approach I'd have to prompt each time which I want to avoid. i'll try HansUp's suggestion now.

Comment: I've changed the type on the quarter field to "Number" though it has just deleted the quarter number for 26,000 records. Would there be a way to do this without changing the data type?

Comment: Did you try passing the binary value of the number? 1 = 1, 2 = 10, 3 = 11, 4 = 100

Comment: i'll see where that gets me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I passed Qrtnum in as 100 and it still gave me the mismatch error.

Comment: Could someone help me out here please. Does Access support **Binary**? Or does that data type even exist?

Comment: When issuing a `DELETE` statement in SQL, do you have to issue the column names? I thought it would be: `"DELETE FROM SampledEmailAddressesByQuarter WHERE SampledEmailAddressesByQuarter.Quarter = num`

Comment: @PaulFrancis - Access does support binary. The name of the column is masked as "Attachment" (I believe), but the underlying column type is binary.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner, thank you. That is what I had come to a conclusion too. However, given that. I am confused how a `DELETE` or `SELECT` could be possible. Well I am watching this thread to know how.

Comment: I've added a debug line to see what the SQL actually is and it shows as follows: `DELETE FROM SampledEmailAddressesByQuarter WHERE SampledEmailAddressesByQuarter.Quarter = 4`

Comment: @PaulFrancis Re binary, see [Microsoft Access Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714540(v=vs.85).aspx).  Although binary is available, I don't think it's a good choice for storing integer values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit of a cop out answer, but the credit should go to @HansUp. In the end I converted the data type of the field to number and managed to copy in all the data after. My code works fine now it's not trying to deal with a Binary data type. Still interested to know how I'd deal with this though. Thanks for all the help.